# How to fix conflicts after rebase and push them

Tags: git, branch, rebase

In our project we use git, every feature we release in new branch and after codereview CTO rebases it into the develop branch. After I finished my ticket CTO said that he can't rebase my changes bc conflicts occured. I reproduced it on local machine:

```
git clone ...
cd project1
git checkout my-branch
git rebase develop
...
Auto-merging admin/contest.html
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in admin/contest.html
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0019 contest: admin, dashboard, /contest

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

Ok, I resolved this conflict, than added this file but I can't continue rebase or push something. What is the best way to resolve such conflicts?

**UPDATE**

After I did *git rebase --continue* I got:

```
Applying: $0 in admin/contest dropdown
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

Comment: What is the issue when you run `git rebase --continue`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rebase, whether interactive or not, works by repeating a simple cherry-picking process.

First let's define a "cherry pick".

Suppose you have a branch (e.g., a production branch) that is not ready to be upgraded generally, but you also have a bug.  Suppose further that, on a development branch, someone already fixed that particular bug, and the fix is simple and clean and will work in the production code.  (For instance, changing one line in `fileA` and two lines in `fileB` fixes the problem, and this can be done on the production branch.)

You could:

```
$ git show 15fd3dc > /tmp/bug-fix
```

to see the change and write the patch to a file, and then manually copy in the patch and `git add` and `git commit`.  Or you could even do the above, or use `git format-patch`, and then use `git apply` or `git am` to import the patch to branch `production`.  But it's even easier: you can simply get on branch `production` and use:

```
$ git cherry-pick 15fd3dc
```

and git will, in essence, extract the fix and apply and commit it, all automatically.  In other words, it *copies* a commit.

Now let's consider a `rebase`.  Here we have something like this:

```
... o - o - o - * - * - X - * - *   <-- your-work
              \
                o - Y - Z   <-- their-work
```

I've labeled one of your commits `X` and two of theirs `Y` and `Z`, just so that I can make something special happen with them later.  First let's just look at the mechanics of the rebase.

To do the rebase, git simply needs to take each of your commits (the `*` ones, along with `X` in the middle) and cherry-pick them onto the end of `their-work`.  That is, we create a new temporary branch and start copying commits:

```
... o - o - o - * - * - X - * - *   <-- your-work
              \
                o - Y - Z   <-- their-work
                          \
                            * - *   <-- temp-branch
```

In many cases, all the commits copy over trivially: there are no conflicts and all your commits cherry-pick cleanly.  In that case, git then does the final step: erase the old branch label `your-work`, and change the branch label `temp-branch` to `your-work`, so that your (copied) commits now sit atop commit `Z`.

In this case, however, there was a conflict when trying to cherry-pick commit `X`.  It conflicted with one or both of commits `Y` and `Z`: those other two commits changed something in the same region where your change in `X` goes.

This is where rebase stops and gives you the message you saw:

> ```
> When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
> If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
> To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
> ```

You begin the manual resolving, by editing the conflicted files (with your merge tool rather than with a plain text editor, but the effect is the same) and `git add`ing the final files.

Next, you run `git rebase --continue`.  At this point there are two possibilities (assuming you *did* remember to `git add` files as needed):

1. You still have some change from the previous revision (`Z` if this is the first commit being copied, or one of the copies of your `*` commits if later; given where I drew `X`, this would be one of those copies).
2. You actually have removed all your changes during the conflict resolution.  Perhaps commit `Y` had half of what you did, and then commit `Z` had the rest of it, so now your commit `X` is redundant with those two commits.

You appear to have hit case (2).  In case (1), `git rebase --continue` just goes on to copy the rest of the `*` commits, and then moves your branch label.  In case (2), however, `git rebase --continue` complains:

> ```
> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
> If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
> already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.
> ```

In this case (and *only* if you *did not* forget to do the `git add` step), you should, as the next bit tells you, use `git rebase --skip`.  This tells git to forget about your earlier commit `X` entirely, and go on to cherry-pick the remaining `*` commits.

Comment: Thank you for such awesome answer! It works correct if I *checkout --theirs* changes, continue rebasing I got a few files to change, finally the rebase is ok. How to do a patch that can be added to my branch to avoid conflicts on the product  server?

Comment: I don't understand that last question.  Note that `checkout --theirs` in a rebase actually gets you *your* version (the `--ours` and `--theirs` flags to checkout are with respect to `git merge`; the cherry picks that rebase uses, use merge, but swap the "sides" of ours/theirs in the process), so it might be right, but it might lose stuff they actually did (in revs `Y` and/or `Z` above, in my illustration).